# Reading from a File in C , problems with fscanf functions

Tags: c, file, scanf, gets

My program is supposed to read from a file and fill some structs that are like post from a social network , and then fill a Queue structure with the info from the file. But the main problem seems to be the reading from file function that is posted below:

```
int load_user_from_file(struct Coda* Bacheca,char* nome_file){
    
    FILE* fp=fopen(nome_file,"r");
    
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("errore lettura file");
        return -1;
        
    }else{
        printf("\nFile in lettura...");
    }
    
    int len=64;
    char tmp_msg[len];
    int tmp_n_like;
    char* buffer ;
    
    while(fgets(tmp_msg,len,fp) != NULL  ){
            
                fscanf(fp,"%s",buffer);
        tmp_n_like=getw(fp);
        
        printf("Eureka\n");
        
        printf("%s %d\n",tmp_msg,tmp_n_like);
        
        struct Post* new_post = generate_Post(tmp_msg,tmp_n_like); 
        insert_in_queue(Bacheca,*new_post);
    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

(sorry for formatting errors , i am quite a noob on the forum =( )

and the .txt file looks like this (sorry for it being in Italian):

[image]

The first string being the msg of the post and below there is the number of likes.

I tried various methods to get the string and the integer below to fill all the posts.
I read other posts about this but still can't figure it out , sorry if I  had to make another post.
Sometimes the number is incorrect or it does not read anything. I know it's a problem with buffers and in particular the spaces in the string but i really can't figure it out. I am quite close now with this as i get this :

[image]

It looks like it gets the first number of the date of post for the integer of the likes
then he adds more post the needed using both the integer as the msg and as the number of likes.

How should i fix this? Much help needed here XP

Comment: The biggest problem in your code is that you `fscanf` into a `buffer` which is not initialized. `fscanf` requires allocated memory, it won't allocate it for you.

Comment: What is `getw(fp)`? Perhaps turn your example into a [mcve] (which it isn't at the moment)? Perhaps in the process turning the Italian into English? But fukanchik already pointed out the one big error there. And if you know you're reading an `int`, why not use `%d` to read an `int` directly instead of a `%s`?

Comment: Why are you using `fgets` *and* `fscanf` *and* `getw`? Especially `getw`. Where did you find information about `getw`? What do you think this function does?

Comment: @fukanchik Hi thanks for the help , but i don't know how much should i allocate for a buffer? Would a Static allocation like " char buffer[256] " do it ? what should i write in the malloc for this?

Comment: `char buffer[256]` is fine *if you limit the input to 256 chars* (`%255s`). Generally speaking, it is recommended practice to read full lines (`fgets`) and then do parsing in-memory (e.g. using `strtol`).

Comment: @DevSolar I had problems using fscanf to get that integer then i looked online for other ways to read from a file , and found that getw reads intger from files. I was quite desperate at that point.  For the other part of the question I used a %s bcs i am trying to get the buffer out the way and not read the integer , that is something i tried to do on the next line with the getw ( but clearly all of this doesn't work as i intended D: )

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Is it possible to read everything with just fgets ? I read that it only gets strings am i wrong? fscanf has a lot of problems with the spaces soo i tried to avoid it for the string.

Comment: Ok so i followed your instructions, got rid of the getw. Now i use a fscanf for the integer in the while cicle. The result is the same as posted. I removed the char* buffer as it was not needed entirely. Now i just need the fscanf to not take the first number from the string as the integer and skip to the number of likes. How can i do that?

Comment: You can read lines with fgets, then parse each line as needed (e.g. with sscanf). Using fscanf and fgets together is error-prone and not recommended.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) [Edit] your question and copy&paste input and output *as text* and format it as code blocks. Make your code a [mre]. Add the modified code and show the corresponding actual and expected output.